# How can I print number of mouse clicks in Roblox Studio

Tags: lua, click, mouse, roblox

I have created a text button in ScreenGui. I want to print the number of clicks each time someone clicks that TextButton. I have written the following code in LocalScript of ScreenGui:

```
local UserInputService = game:GetService("UserInputService")
local clicked=0
    
while true do

UserInputService.InputEnded:Connect(function(input)
    if input.UserInputType == Enum.UserInputType.MouseButton1 then
        clicked = clicked+1
        print("Clicked "..clicked)
        wait(0.5)
        
    end
end)
if clicked>4 then
    break
end
```

However, whenever I run this code and click once it prints clicked random number of times (54 times or 100 times and so on). When I click second time it prints 500 times.

Can anyone help me with the code and make it print only the exact number of clicks on the TextButton?

Answer (score 2):

You have a TextButton, just use the [MouseButton1Click](https://create.roblox.com/docs/reference/engine/classes/GuiButton#MouseButton1Click) event. Also, using `while true do` is just going to freeze up your client as you're adding a new connection and there's no `wait()`. Check for the `clicked` variable update in the event handler instead. Example:

```lua
local btn = script.Parent
local clicked = 0

local function cb() 
   -- code to call when clicked is more than 4
end

local conn; conn = btn.MouseButton1Click:Connect(function() 
    if clicked > 4 then 
        conn:Disconnect(); -- disconnect the connection so it stops recieving events
        cb() 
    else
        clicked += 1 -- increase click by 1
    end
end)
```

Comment: rfl890, thanks for the response.